# Store array from select field

Tags: php, laravel, multiple-select

I am trying to store an array of counties in my database. Here's my blade:

```
<select size="5" name="county[]" multiple class="form-control-2">
<option value="" selected="" disabled="">All Counties</option>
@if (isset($counties))
    @foreach ($counties as $c)
        <option value="{{ $c->name }}">{{ $c->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

and my controller is:

```
// Store the property Alert
 public function propertyAlert(PropertyAlertRequest $request)
 {
         $action = PropertySubscribe::create($request->all());
         $action = PropertySubscribe::create([
            $action->county = Input::get('county'),
            ]);
         $action->save();

     notify()->flash('Registered!', 'success', ['text' => 'You have now been registered.']);
     return back();
 }
```

and the error I am getting is:

```
preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array
```

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong? I am sending it as an array and the dd is showing the values successfully. Do I need to foreach on the array items?

Comment: Why mix a Facade with Dependency Injection?  You have the $request injected so you don't need to use `Input::`.  Use `$request->input('county')`.

Answer (score 0):

`Input::get('county')` is returning an array, because your `select multiple`

try this:

```
foreach(Input::get('county') as $county)
{
    PropertySubscribe::create([
        $action->county = $county,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: @PaoloResteghini well what does PropertySubscribe::create expect?  You are passing a multi-dimensional array in your question, this is a single dimensional array.

Comment: I think it's a typo.  `$action->county => $county,` but that still doesn't make sense, the left side should be the name of a column.

Comment: @PaoloResteghini take a look in your `$fillable property` at model, If you are using `..::create([ ...]), you dont need `->save()`